# Getting the value on the left hand side of the equation using regex in perl

Tags: regex, perl

INPUT.txt

```
textbig  = functionX(parameter1, parameter2);

textsmall= functionX(parameter3, parameter4);
```

The input file is as shown above. From this file, using Perl and regex, I have to read each line and put the first word that is read into a variable, as shown below:

```
$variable1 = textbig;

$variable2 = textsmall;
```

I am reading each line, but unable to grab the first word from each line. I tried $1 method but it's not helpful.

Comment: Show what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

One option here would be to do a regex split on the pattern `\s*=\s*`, and then just retain the first portion of that split:

```
my $input = 'textbig = functionX(parameter1, parameter2);'; 
my @output = split /\s*=\s*/, $input;
print $output[0];
```

This prints:

```
textbig
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my ($left_of_first_equal) = $string =~ /^([^=]*)=/;
```